# SQL multiple select with where conditions performs really poorly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, sql-server-2005, subquery, query-performance

Data structure is something like this:

```
Number| ID | DateTime | Status

50000001, 101, 1/1/09 0:10, PO
50000001, 110, 1/1/09 0:11, PO
50000001, 102, 1/1/09 0:15, PO
50000001, 101, 1/1/09 0:10, PCK 
50000001, 102, 1/1/09 0:12, PCK 
50000001, 110, 1/1/09 0:12, PCK 
50000001, 101, 1/1/09 0:15, C 
50000001, 101, 1/1/09 0:15, C+
50000001, 110, 1/1/09 0:15, C 
50000001, 110, 1/1/09 0:15, C+
50000001, 102, 1/1/09 0:15, C 
50000001, 102, 1/1/09 0:15, C+
50000002, 126, 1/1/09 0:13, WO
50000002, 126, 1/1/09 0:14, PCK 
50000002, 126, 1/1/09 0:14, C 
50000002, 126, 1/1/09 0:14, S
```

I am trying to select data based on several values in the Status column and return it formatted like:

```
| Number | OrderOpen | OrderCleared |
```

My query looks like this:

```
Select 
SetOpen.ID, SetOpen.Num, SetOpen.OrderOpen, SetCleared.OrderCleared
FROM 
(
SELECT
    order_status_hist.ID AS 'ID',
    order_status_hist.Number AS 'Num',
    order_status_hist.datetime AS 'OrderOpen' 
FROM 
    dbo.order_status_hist
WHERE 
    order_status_hist.Status='WO' OR 
    order_status_hist.Status='PO'
) as SetOpen
inner JOIN
(
SELECT
    order_status_hist.ID AS 'ID',
    order_status_hist.Number AS 'Num',
    order_status_hist.datetime AS 'OrderCleared' 
FROM 
    order_status_hist
WHERE 
(
    order_status_hist.Status='C+' OR 
    order_status_hist.Status='S' 
)
) AS SetCleared

ON SetOpen.ID = SetCleared.ID
```

In my production database there are about 50 values in the status column, and my where statements have 10 'cases' in the first one and 5 in the second one. When I run the production version of this, it takes a VERY long time to complete. The further trouble is, this is really just part of a larger query, I would be joining these results on 'Number' to pull data in more tables.

Comment: Can you show us the create table for `order_status_hist` including any indexes defined, and can you post the execution plan somewhere?

Comment: In case you need a somewhere to uh.. Paste The Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ (full disclosure: I work for the company that hosts it).

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik sorry, I should have linked that. We also offer a way to upload plans, but I try to stay away from pushing that

Comment: @AaronBertrand where is the link to the way you offer to upload plans?

Comment: @mercello [answers.sqlperformance.com](https://answers.sqlperformance.com) using [Plan Explorer](https://sentryone.com/plan-explorer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this heap:

```
CREATE TABLE #foo(Number int, ID tinyint, [DateTime] datetime, [Status] varchar(10));

INSERT #foo(Number,ID,[DateTime],[Status]) VALUES
(50000001, 101, '1/1/2009 0:10', 'PO'),
(50000001, 110, '1/1/2009 0:11', 'PO'),
(50000001, 102, '1/1/2009 0:15', 'PO'),
(50000001, 101, '1/1/2009 0:10', 'PCK'), 
(50000001, 102, '1/1/2009 0:12', 'PCK'), 
(50000001, 110, '1/1/2009 0:12', 'PCK'), 
(50000001, 101, '1/1/2009 0:15', 'C'),
(50000001, 101, '1/1/2009 0:15', 'C+'),
(50000001, 110, '1/1/2009 0:15', 'C'),
(50000001, 110, '1/1/2009 0:15', 'C+'),
(50000001, 102, '1/1/2009 0:15', 'C'),
(50000001, 102, '1/1/2009 0:15', 'C+'),
(50000002, 126, '1/1/2009 0:13', 'WO'),
(50000002, 126, '1/1/2009 0:14', 'PCK'), 
(50000002, 126, '1/1/2009 0:14', 'C'),
(50000002, 126, '1/1/2009 0:14', 'S');
```

This query drops it from two scans to a single scan, gets rid of a hash match, and shifts most of the cost to a sort:

```
SELECT
  ID, Num = Number,
  OrderOpen    = MIN(CASE WHEN [Status] IN ('WO','PO') THEN [DateTime] END),
  OrderCleared = MAX(CASE WHEN [Status] IN ('S','C+')  THEN [DateTime] END)
FROM #foo
GROUP BY ID, Number;
```

This PIVOT is also cheaper, but still has the expensive sort:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT ID, Number, [DateTime], BetterStatus = CASE 
    WHEN [Status] IN ('WO','PO') THEN 'OrderOpen'
    WHEN [Status] IN ('S', 'C+') THEN 'OrderCleared' END
  FROM #foo
) AS f
PIVOT
(
  MAX([Datetime]) FOR BetterStatus IN ([OrderOpen],[OrderCleared])
) AS p;
GO
```

However, if we add a computed column and an index:

```
ALTER TABLE #foo ADD BetterStatus AS CONVERT(varchar(12), 
  ISNULL(CASE WHEN [Status] IN ('WO','PO') THEN 'OrderOpen'
       WHEN [Status] IN ('S','C+')  THEN 'OrderCleared' END, '?'));
GO
CREATE INDEX x ON #foo(Number, ID, [Datetime], BetterStatus);
GO
```

Then these two queries fare much better (both producing ordered scans without any additional sorting required):

```
SELECT
  ID, Num = Number,
  OrderOpen    = MIN(CASE [BetterStatus] WHEN 'OrderOpen' THEN [DateTime] END),
  OrderCleared = MAX(CASE [BetterStatus] WHEN 'OrderCleared' THEN [DateTime] END)
FROM #foo
GROUP BY ID, Number;

SELECT ID, Num, OrderOpen, OrderCleared
FROM 
(
  SELECT ID, Num = Number, [DateTime], BetterStatus FROM #foo
) AS f
PIVOT
(
  MAX([Datetime]) FOR BetterStatus IN ([OrderOpen],[OrderCleared])
) AS p;
```

So, if you don't have supporting indexes and/or can't add computed columns or new indexes, use one of the first two queries, and if you can add these items (or modify existing indexes to achieve the same effect), use one of the latter two.

This isn't exhaustive tuning, of course. Just a kickstart.

Comment: Arron, option #1 is spot on. Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm a long time network admin, but got wrapped into this data export project. I understand the difference in the sorts but I wasn't able to get that into the TSQL. Next time I will post the table create right off the bat.... but I'm not super clear as to what the execution plan is, I will figure it out as well. Thanks again.